# Symfony 4 : how to make a login space secured without security?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have to make an admin access control on a Symfony 4 project. Everyone is using Security-bundle but for technical reasons related to the OVH servers, we can not upgrade the MySQL version from 5.6 to 5.7.

Indeed Security has to be used with MySQL 5.7 because the User entity created with Security is using a JSON format that is impossible to decode with an anterior version.

But without installing Security, I have no access to the config/packages/security.yaml and I really don't know how to create my login fonction. If I create that file, that will browse an error :

"There is no extension able to load the configuration for "security" Looked for namespace "security", found "framework", "web_server", "maker", "doctrine_cache", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "twig", "swiftmailer", "sensio_framework_extra", "knp_paginator" "

I saw that another librairy FOSUSERBundle is existing, but it seems deprecated for Symfony 4.

So what should I do ? Do you know a way to create a login form **secured** with a password crypted in a User entity without the bundle Security ?

Comment: You can use the standard php function `password_hash` and verify it with `password_verify`. It sounds like you will need to create all the UI/Logic yourself though

Comment: What `User` entity are you referring to? You can create a class that is shaped according to your project's needs. There is no requirement to have it use an incompatible JSON format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SecurityBundle with an older MySQL version. In fact the problem with the JSON field is not related to the SecurityBundle at all, but rather Doctrine DBAL.

In your `config.yaml` look for the doctrine settings and inside that block look for the version which by default will use 5.7. When you change this setting, then Doctrine will recognize that it can't use the JSON-type and fall back to a varchar(?) field or something else. You might have to update your schema (locally) to reflect that change. It should give you a result that should look like your production setup on your hosting infrastructure.